# I want date time before paricular seconds

Tags: php, date, time

I am showing the result of the Quiz in which I get time taken by the user to pay Quiz. and present date time. from which I want to show the start time and finish time.

from the present date and time I get finish time but for start time I am trying to get date and time from time taken before present date time.

for that, I am doing this code but it's not working.

I am putting my code below.

```
<?php
 $timeTaken = $_POST['timeTaken'];
 date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
 $date = date("D d M Y h:i A");
 $started_date = date("$date", time() - gmdate("H:i:s", $timeTaken));
?>
```

where my timeTaken is 00:00:05 means $timeTaken = '05'; how can I get start date time?

can anybody help me in this...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing exactly, but relying on user input to determine the time taken for a quiz seems like a bad idea: A user could change it to whatever he/she wants.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if `$timeTaken` was a number representing the time taken in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This

```
<?php
    $timeTaken = $_POST['timeTaken'];
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
    $timeArr = explode(':', $timeTaken);
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo $started_date = $date->sub(new DateInterval('PT'.$timeArr[0].'H'.$timeArr[1].'M'.$timeArr[2].'S'))->format('D d M Y h:i:s A');
?>
```

Use the new `DateTime` function  and subtract the hour minute and date from the current time.. which will give you the desired result. Also i have added seconds in date format